# How to access $_$ESSION data stored in array code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have been following a [tutorial on youtube about CodeIgniter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay_w82osHpM). The tutorial only relies on `$username` `$_SESSION` variable and doesn't touch on other aspects of `$_SESSION`s. According to [code igniter documentation regarding `$_SESSION`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) you can simply call the session super global with the key. This is where my problem starts.

**`VAR_DUMP($_SESSION)`**

a `var_dump` of $_Session provides the following info (I have truncated other fields to keep it shorter)

```
 array (size=5)
      '__ci_last_regenerate' => int 1526800056
      '' => null
      'userID' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=14)
              'userID' => string '1' (length=1)
              'firstname' => string 'Tim' (length=3)
              'lastname' => string 'Coetzee' (length=7)
              'pword' => string 'xyz' (length=4)
              'email' => string 'someone@gmail.com' (length=17)
```

**What I want to do**

I simply want to be able to call a `$_SESSION` super global as such `$_SESSION['email']` or `$_SESSION['userID']` The way I want to access the session vars is EXACTLY as you should do it according to docs, thus I believe my
problem is in my controller() or the way im setting the session data() as can be viewed below

**Problem**

Lets say I want to display the `userID` from above `var_dump()` info in the view just as a test I do the following... `echo $_SESSION['userID'];`

The above leads to error

> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Okay sure enough however what is the object name I should call to get say `firstname` ?

I tried this as per official docs

`echo $this->session->firstname` AND `echo $this->user_data('userID');`
 which resulted in same error.

I realize the $_SESSION data seems to be saved in a multi-dimensional array so I tried a `foreach()` as such

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $sessions)
{
    foreach ($sessions as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

which gives me the error:

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

However after two more similar errors by the last iteration it returns the values of all the sessions, so Im guessing im doing something wrong in the loop.

### Code Follows Below

**Users_model.php**

```
public function login($username, $password)
    {
        // Validate
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('pword', $password);
        $stmnt = $this->db->get('users');
        if($stmnt->num_rows() == 1){
            return $stmnt->row(1);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function login(){
        $data['title'] = 'Sign In';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            // Get username
            echo $username = $this->input->post('username');
            // Get and encrypt the password
            echo $password = $this->input->post('password');
            // Login user
            $user_id = $this->users_model->login($username, $password);
            if($user_id){
                // Create session
                $user_data = array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'userID' => $user_id,
                    'logged_in' => true
                );
              $username = user_data ['username'];
              $userID = user_data ['userID'];
              $logged_in = user_data ['logged_in']; 

                $this->session->set_userdata($username );
                $this->session->set_userdata($userID );
                $this->session->set_userdata($logged_in);
                // Set message
                //$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');
                redirect('pages/index');
            } else {
                // Set message
               // $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
                redirect('users/failed');
            }
        }
    }
```

**$config.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation','session', 'pagination');
```

Any help advice, or constuctive criticism appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*if you don't want to change your model query set session like this*

```
$user = $this->users_model->login($username, $password);
if($user)
{
    $user_data = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'userID' => $user->id,
                'logged_in' => true
            );
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

    //$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');
    redirect('pages/index');
} 
else 
{
    // Set message
    // $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
    redirect('users/failed');
}
```

*print individual session key like this :*

```
echo $this->session->userdata('username');
echo $this->session->userdata('userID');
echo $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
```

*and whole session like this :*

```
print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

Note :  for **CI Version 3.1.8**, *access like this* :

```
$username = $this->session->username;
$userid = $this->session->userID;
```

for more https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. As mentioned in my question I have already tried it. it results in `: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` when I try `echo $this->session->userID`

Comment: what is your ci version

Comment: ok got you while setting session you are passing whole result from model into userID key that is why you got error there , put just user_id there

Comment: change if  ur <users>'s user id column is not  id

Comment: Hey Pradeep thank you for your ongoing help. If I have  `$user_id = $stmnt->row()->id` I can not login.... it results in failed login

Comment: Pradeep I got it! I should not put `$user_id = $stmnt->row()->id` I should change the `->id` part to `->userID` Thank you for the help

Comment: Hey do you have Skype I am willing to pay for codeigniter tutorials if you are interested.

Comment: really !  r u serious, do you really want tutorial?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171414/discussion-between-timothy-coetzee-and-pradeep).

Answer (score 1):

When you `echo $_SESSION['userID'];` you are trying to display whole array like string, it is immposible.

Also you cannot use two foreach loops because in the first cycle of outer loop there is integer (`'__ci_last_regenerate' => int 1526800056`) as argument of inner loop, so you get error.

Following your session array structure you can call to fields like that:
`echo $_SESSION['userID'][0]['firstname'];`

or better:

`$name = $this->session->userdata('firstname');`

Comment: Hello Robin thank you for your input: `$_SESSION['userID'][0]['firstname']` leads to ` Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in` and ` $this->session->userdata('userID')` results in `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` Im not quite sure why it is so hard to work pass this, could you prehaps look at my controller() I might be doing something wrong there. Thank you

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I see problem is solved. So all i can say now it's to not storing passwords as plain text. And good luck

Comment: Hey @Robin71 thanks mate yeah I removed the encryption part as part of the debugging process but yup 100% agree security is key (get it!)